# How can i swap every 2 bits in a binary number?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on this programming project and part of it is to write a function with just bitwise operators that switches every two bits.  I've come up with a comb sort of algorithm that accomplishes this but it only works for unsigned numbers, any ideas how I can get it to work with signed numbers as well? I'm completely stumped on this one.  Heres what I have so far:

```
        // Mask 1 - For odd bits
    int a1 = 0xAA; a1 <<= 24;
    int a2 = 0xAA; a2 <<= 16;
    int a3 = 0xAA; a3 <<= 8;
    int a4 = 0xAA;
    int mask1 = a1 | a2 | a3 | a4;

    // Mask 2 - For even bits
    int b1 = 0x55; b1 <<= 24;
    int b2 = 0x55; b2 <<= 16;
    int b3 = 0x55; b3 <<= 8;
    int b4 = 0x55;
    int mask2 = b1 | b2 | b3 | b4;

    // Mask Results
    int odd = x & mask1;
    int even = x & mask2;

    int newNum = (odd >> 1) | (even << 1);

    return newNum;
```

The manual creation of the masks by or'ing variables together is because the only constants that can be used are between 0x00-0xFF.

Comment: What if you just did this one byte at a time instead of the whole 32 bit word? Same basic technique.

Comment: shot-in-the-dark: revisiting bitlab are we?

Comment: `mask1 = mask2 << 1;` can reduce a lot of operators. Check also `mask2 = 0x55; mask2=mask2 | (mask2<<8); mask2=mask2|(mask2<<16)`

Comment: Beware the sign bit with those signed int right shifts.

Comment: Hint: the two masks differ by a single shift.

Comment: The shift to create the second mask helped a lot with operators! thanks! down to 13 and the function is now working.

Comment: "the only constants that can be used are between 0x00-0xFF"  Why is that?

Comment: its an old lab with certain requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `odd >> 1` will sign extend with negative numbers. Simply do another `and` to eliminate the duplicated bit.

```
int newNum = ((odd >> 1) & mask2) | (even << 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing the operators and noticing the sign extension problem gives:

```
int odd = 0x55;
odd |= odd << 8;
odd |= odd << 16;

int newnum =   ((x & odd) << 1 )  // This is (sort of well defined)
             | ((x >> 1) & odd);  // this handles the sign extension without
                                  // additional & -operations
```

One remark though: bit twiddling should be generally applied to unsigned integers only.

Comment: Very nice! Yeah the lab uses signed integers in every problem to make things a pain in the ass. nice of them.

Answer (score 0):

When you right shift a signed number, the sign will also be extended. This is known as [sign extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). Typically when you are dealing with bit shifting, you want to use unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Minimizing use of constants by working one byte at a time:

```
unsigned char* byte_p;
unsigned char byte;
int ii;
byte_p = &x;   
for(ii=0; ii<4; ii++) {
  byte = *byte_p;
  *byte_p = ((byte & 0xAA)>>1) | ((byte & 0x55) << 1);
  byte_p++;
}
```

Minimizing operations and keeping constants between `0x00` and `0xFF`:

```
unsigned int comb = (0xAA << 8) + 0xAA;
comb += comb<<16;
newNum = ((x & comb) >> 1) | ((x & (comb >> 1)) << 1);
```

10 operations.

Just saw the comments above and realize this is implementing (more or less) some of the suggestions that @akisuihkonen made. So consider this a tip of the hat!

Comment: I just realized you said "minimize operators" not "minimize constants". I will re-think this a bit.